# Conditional exogeneity when regressors are causally, linearly related

Tags: regression, least-squares, endogeneity, exogeneity, gauss-markov-theorem

Let's say there is a multiple regression:
$$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \beta_3X_3 + \beta_4X_4 + \beta_5X_5+U.
$$
I know that conditional exogeneity implies that the error terms are mean independent as a function of all $X$ variables jointly. For example, wage = education + ability violates exogeneity because ability (the error term) affects both education and wage.

However, in the regression above, if $X_4$ affects $X_1$, (i.e. increase of $X_4$ decreases $X_1$), then would that also be a violation of exogeneity? Would that violate any other three of the Gauss-Markov assumptions?

Comment: What is multivariate OLS? Do you mean you have a multivariate regression where each equation is estimated separately by OLS (equation-by-equation OLS)?

Comment: I meant multivariable OLS! Just a regression with multiple variables

Comment: What you want is called multiple regression. What you write is a set of regressions. I have edited to clarify.